# Search a column for a 1 and paste entire row to another worksheet when found?

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with a bit of code that is getting stuck in a loop. I am trying to get the code to copy any rows where the values in column BD is 1 and paste the values for that entire row in to the next empty row in another worksheet. The code i am using is as below

```
Sub FindIssues()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
Sheets("Macro Worksheet").Select
If Range("BD" & i).Value = "1" Then Rows(i).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Loop
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Macro Worksheet").Select


Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not use [AUTOFILTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro Worksheet

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyEntireRow()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = Sheets("Macro Worksheet")

    Dim trgt As Worksheet
    Set trgt = Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To src.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If src.Range("A" & i) = 1 Then
            ' calling the copy paste procedure
            CopyPaste src, i, trgt
        End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

' this sub copoes and pastes the entire row into a different sheet
' below the last used row
Private Sub CopyPaste(ByRef src As Worksheet, ByVal i As Long, ByRef trgt As Worksheet)
    src.Activate
    src.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
    trgt.Activate
    Dim nxtRow As Long
    nxtRow = trgt.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    trgt.Rows(nxtRow & ":" & nxtRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Macro Worksheet 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've replicated your 2 sheets with column A on Macro Worksheet containing

[image]

and column BD containing 1s in rows 3 and 5

[image]

So I expect rows 3 and 5 to copy to  rows 1 and 2 of Macro Worksheet 2.

When I run FindIssues with **a blank** cell A1 selected on macro Worksheet I get the unexpected result of

[image]

If you look at and step through your code (reformatted and commented):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindIssues()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    Sheets("Macro Worksheet").Select

    'Select the i row if if BD = 1
    If Range("BD" & i).Value = "1" Then Rows(i).Select

    'else just copy the current selection
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2").Select

    'then paste it into A1 on Macro Sheet 2
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'then find the first empty row on Macro Sheet 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    'and repaste the copied cells there
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Macro Worksheet").Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Stepping through the code, when i=2 BD is blank the currently selected A1 is copied to A1 and A2 on Macro Worksheet 2.

When i = 3 BD has a 1 in it so it gets copied to A1 on Macro Worksheet 2 and then pasted into A3 as well.

And so on it goes with each row having 1 in BD being copied once into A1 and then into the next empty row.

So you need to get rid of the code that copies into A1

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The other problem area is around

```
    If Range("BD" & i).Value = "1" Then Rows(i).Select
```

because IF BD doesn't equal 1, the code below your IF statement is executed anyway **but it copies the selection from the prior iteration of the loop** (i.e. the selection hasn't changed):

```
        'else just copy the current selection
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2").Select

    'then find the first empty row on Macro Sheet 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    'and repaste the copied cells there
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

If you change your code to put those commands **within the IF statement** it looks like this

```
Sub FindIssues()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR
        Sheets("Macro Worksheet").Select

        'Select the i row if if BD = 1
        If Range("BD" & i).Value = "1" Then
            Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2").Select

            'then find the first empty row on Macro Sheet 2
            Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
               ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Loop

            'and repaste the copied cells there
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("Macro Worksheet").Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It's probably a bit pedantic but it reduces the code lines

- avoid *selecting* objects in your code; it just slows things down!
- do copy/paste on one line of code

and this is one possible solution:

```
Sub FindIssues()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim LR2 As String
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR

        'Test if BD equals 1
        If Range("BD" & i).Value = "1" Then

            'set the next row on Macro Worksheet 2 (assuming no blanks)
            LR2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2").Range("A:A")) + 1

            'copy row i to the destination
            Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Macro Worksheet 2").Range(LR2 & ":" & LR2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which gives this result On Macro Worksheet 2
[image]